# Extract table data from PDF that is formatted as picture

Tags: r, pdf, ocr

I am trying to extract the data in the tables that start on p.52 of this [document](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/controller_staffing/media/2017_CWP.pdf) (a report from FAA).

The problem is that the tables are included as pictures. Any chance I can get some pointers on how to do that without doing it manually?

I have tried converting it to text using Adobe's OCR function, and I have also tried using the extract_tables function in R's tabulized package.

I could of course do this manually, but it would be good to know if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: If it's stored as an image, you have to use OCR, because libraries like `tabulizer` read the underlying PostScript from the PDF file. R has OCR libraries, and for an image like the one in your PDF it may be fairly accurate, but it's not an exact science.

Comment: The `tesseract` library might be a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, however its accuracy depends on the image. I always use grayscale images. [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/59394/570442) an example of available tools. In your case, I'd suggest you take some screenshots of the tables and use the OCRFeeder to compare the results from GOCR and Tesseract.

```
sudo apt-get install gocr tesseract-ocr ocrfeeder

ocrfeeder -i image.jpg
```

After some manual checks, you can import this file in LibreOffice Calc, save it as 'csv', and import in R.